# I want NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip() to show baloon tooltip on top of all windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip() in my application, but its balloon tip is not always visible. For example, it's not visible when I play a game (in Windowed Fullscreen mode).

How can I make it visible on top of other windows?

I understand that maybe this behavior is controlled by Windows and cannot be changed, but maybe someone knows a secret :) Also, if you know any other way to show balloon tooltips on top of other windows, please share.

**Edit 1:**
I'm writing my own Time Manager, so for example at 19:00 it should notify me that it's time to   do something important. If I'm playing a game (most games offer Windowed video mode, but still I noticed that during playing some games I see tray notifications, and during playing some others - notifications are not visible) at 19:00 I will miss that notification. What can you suggest?

Comment: And then the next developer comes along and needs a way to place a window on top of everything so that even **sooooper** important balloon messages don't interrupt their experience. Do you not see that this is a futile arms race? Balloon messages aren't meant to be used to tell the user that the world is coming to an end - they let the user know something, but they're **meant** to be ignorable.

Comment: You might also want to review some blog posts by Raymond Chen. [This one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) seems like a decent starting point, but basically look around on his blog for terms such as "walls and ladders"

Comment: I edited my question. Can you offer something?

Comment: Yeah, come on guys, more downvotes instead of answering the question!

Comment: You may have the noblest of intentions. Unfortunately, there's no way, as yet, to distinguish between software with noble intentions and software with malevolent intentions. If there were then we'd have one piece of AV software that never needs updating. And so the current software landscape leaves us dealing with the worst of software, not the best.

Comment: The balloon tip might not be the right tool for the job. You could pop up a new window set to topmost instead, and style it more like a balloon tip. That won't guarantee that it's truly on top, though, for the reasons that everyone else has mentioned.

Comment: @JonB - I like being "everyone else" when until now I seem to be the only responder :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ha! Somehow I hadn't noticed. I think I was giving the comment upvoters credit :)

Comment: Regardless of intentions it, seems like some application are able to display their balloons over top of full screen applications, so there must be some way to do this.

Comment: If you find that you simply can't solve this problem, perhaps you could settle for second best and use a different alert method, like playing a sound. This may have the secondary advantage of being less obtrusive if you're playing a game.